# Jquery no effect on element added with replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using replaceWith to add a common navigation bar to multiple pages.

After the replaceWith() I want to add the "active" class to one of the li elements to make the link seem active.

The code has no effect on runtime. But when I run $("#link1").addClass("active") afterwards in Chrome Snippets it works as expected.

```
<body>
<div id='nav-placeholder'></div>

<script>
        $.get("static/html/navbar.html", function(data){
          $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
        });
        //There is an <li> element in navbar.html with id="link1"
        $("#link1").addClass("active");
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: try `$(document).ready(function() { ... your code ... });`

Comment: Nope, has no effect. I added console.log() before and after the addClass() and both got printed, but no effect on the link.

Comment: `$.get()` is an **asynchronous** operation. The code in the callback executes when the HTTP request completes. The code right after the `$.get()` executes immediately, before that callback is called.

Comment: It would probably work if you just moved the `.addClass()` line inside the callback (after the `.replaceWith()`).

Comment: That worked! So simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id='nav-placeholder'></div>

<script>
        $.get("static/html/navbar.html", function(data){
          $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
          $("#link1").addClass("active");
        });        
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution as @Pointy suggested in the comments also

Answer (score 0):

Try [chaining the jQuery methods](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/introduction/method-chaining/) like this:

```
<body>
<div id='nav-placeholder'></div>

<script>
        $.get("static/html/navbar.html", function(data){
          $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data).find("#link1").addClass("active");
        });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Still no effect on the link with chaining

Comment: This will have problems because the targetted element (nav-placeholder) is being replaced.